# Running Python in terminal and Getting a ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, librosa

Trying to run this python code from my terminal but I am receiving this error. What is happening is I am just trying to find/use a way to classify music based on the spectrogram using librosa library.

$python3 get_genre.py ../test.mp3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_genre.py", line 61, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "get_genre.py", line 50, in main
    pred_genre              = le.inverse_transform(pred_index)
  File "/Users/nico/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 273, in inverse_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/Users/nico/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 760, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Here is the gitHub to all the code in the files being used: https://github.com/cetinsamet/music-genre-classification

This is the get_genre.py code the terminal is running by itself:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import sys

from collections import Counter
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from librosa.core import load
from librosa.feature import melspectrogram
from librosa import power_to_db

from model import genreNet
from config import MODELPATH
from config import GENRES

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


def main(argv):

    if len(argv) != 1:
        print("Usage: python3 get_genre.py audiopath")
        exit()

    le = LabelEncoder().fit(GENRES)
    # ------------------------------- #
    ## LOAD TRAINED GENRENET MODEL
    net         = genreNet()
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODELPATH, map_location='cpu'))
    # ------------------------------- #
    ## LOAD AUDIO
    audio_path  = argv[0]
    y, sr       = load(audio_path, mono=True, sr=22050)
    # ------------------------------- #
    ## GET CHUNKS OF AUDIO SPECTROGRAMS
    S           = melspectrogram(y, sr).T
    S           = S[:-1 * (S.shape[0] % 128)]
    num_chunk   = S.shape[0] / 128
    data_chunks = np.split(S, num_chunk)
    # ------------------------------- #
    ## CLASSIFY SPECTROGRAMS
    genres = list()
    for i, data in enumerate(data_chunks):
        data    = torch.FloatTensor(data).view(1, 1, 128, 128)
        preds   = net(data)
        pred_val, pred_index    = preds.max(1)
        pred_index              = pred_index.data.numpy()[0]
        pred_val                = np.exp(pred_val.data.numpy()[0])
        pred_genre              = le.inverse_transform(pred_index)
        if pred_val >= 0.5:
            genres.append(pred_genre)
    # ------------------------------- #
    s           = float(sum([v for k,v in dict(Counter(genres)).items()]))
    pos_genre   = sorted([(k, v/s*100 ) for k,v in dict(Counter(genres)).items()], key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    for genre, pos in pos_genre:
        print("%10s: \t%.2f\t%%" % (genre, pos))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code works for me, I can pinpoint the cause of the `ValueError`.

Python is throwing that error because the file does not exist, which means that your program does not have access permissions to read from the parent directory.

Copy the `test.mp3` into the `src` directory, then run `python3 get_genre.py test.mp3` and it will work.